# What are some resources for Algebraic quantum mechanics for Physicists

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, operators, resource-recommendations, hilbert-space

I am interested in the GNS construction and other stuff. I am aware of Valter Moretti's book but I want something that is more inclined towards physicists.

Comment: Did you know Strocchi's book? http://www.amazon.it/Introduction-Mathematical-Structure-Quantum-Mechanics/dp/9812835229 in spite of the title it contains many things related to physics other than mathematics.

Comment: Hah, @ValterMoretti himself shows up :D I love how the internet makes this possible!!!

Comment: By the way @ValterMoretti, that should probably be posted as an answer (with a little bit more motivation).

Comment: @ValterMoretti I am currently reading Haag's book and I am finding it hard. Can you suggest something to supplement it.

Comment: I can suggest the lecture notes by J.E. Roberts, "More Lectures on Quantum Field Theory" published in "Noncommutative Geometry" Springer 2000 Editors S. Doplicher and R. Longo